# Installing a NuGet package in project A updated version of an assembly in project B

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have project A and project B in the same solution. I have installed the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` NuGet package in project A, but this updated the version of the `System.Web.Http` assembly in project B, this change is visible in the `App.config` of project B. Project A and project B do not have a relationship of any kind, but as far as I know even if they did, this should not have happened.

[Change in App.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpPxf.png)

Now here are some facts...

- There is no reference to the `System.Web.Http` assembly in `B.csproj`
- `System.Web.Http` is not found in `packages.config` of project B
- It seems like nothing is using the `System.Web.Http` assembly in project B
- When I go to add a new reference, `System.Web.Http` is not even an option, where does it come from? It is also not found in the packages directory of the solution.
- Deleting it from `App.config` of project B does not break anything

I am aware of binding redirects (which is what is happening in App.config of project B), and so I think what happened is someone at some points has installed package A that had a dependency on `System.Web.Http` (eg. version 1.2), then installed `System.Web.Http` (eg. version 1.5) (I don't know how, since I can't seem to find a way to install it), then removed both, but the binding redirect was left in `App.config`.

I am basing the above paragraph on this [blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2012/04/25/when-nuget-adds-bindredirect-elements-to-the-app.config-for-assemblies.aspx).

**But why does it get updated by installing `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` in a completely different and unrelated project?**

Question:

- Where can I find `System.Web.Http` on my system?
- In what scenario would this whole situation be possible? What else should I check?
- Is there anything else I am missing or mis-understanding?

Comment: I agree that it sounds like it shouldn't happen, and therefore I'd need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to debug it.

Comment: What is your project type of project A? I could not reproduce this issue with a sample on my side, just as zivkan said, we need a example to debug this issue, please share a sample to us via one drive.